# Best way to get view models with entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Suppose I have a domain model like this:

```
public class Book
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public DateTime PublicationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }
    public string EnteredBy { get; set; }
}
```

But I want a view model to exclude some fields, like this:

```
public class BookView
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public DateTime PublicationDate { get; set; }
}
```

There's two ways to get view models from the database. First way is this:

```
List<BookView> views = context.Books.Where(b=>b.Author=="Winston Churchill")
    .Select(b=>new BookView() { ID=b.ID,Title=b.Title,Author=b.Author,PublicationDate=b.PublicationDate})
    .ToList();
```

and the second way is this:

```
var results = context.Books.Where(b => b.Author == "Winston Churchill");
List<BookView> views = new List<BookView>();
foreach(var b in results)
{
    views.Add(new BookView() { ID = b.ID,Title = b.Title,Author = b.Author,PublicationDate = b.PublicationDate});        
}
```

My question is does the difference matter at all for performance? The latter would allow more separation of layers--for example the `Book` model could just be in a separate `Data` assembly that doesn't reference the view models at all. But, I wonder if the `Select` clause makes the query more efficient.

Comment: The first approach will throw an exception if the condition won't match. As for the second one you can always check if the list is null. As for performance, it doesn't matter so much. I suggest using `for` loop instead of `foreach`, is a little bit faster for large collections.

Comment: @Cristian Szpisjak what exception does it throw?  I'm not getting an exception when trying this code.

Comment: @Matthew have you tried profiling or any type of performance test?  Have looked at the SQL generated in each case?

Comment: @Cristian Szpisjak it won't throw an exception it will return an empty list.

Comment: @Fran you're right

Answer (score 2):

The "Select" clause does make it more performatic. The select is performed directly on the database, because its an IQuerable object, so you'll only query the fields in the select. The other way, you query all columns and manipulate them in memory.

Comment: not sure about the word performatic. even though i agree with the answer

Comment: performatic means to perform better

Comment: that word doesn't exist.  i think you are looking for performant.  And that's even dicey http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38945/what-is-wrong-with-the-word-performant

Comment: Tell that to google.  https://translate.google.com.br/#en/pt/performatic